# How do to call and execute SSIS package via Windows Service

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, ssis, windows-services

i am trying to load and execute a SSIS package via a windows service. If i run it manually using the command prompt its working great. but if i try to same using a windows service its failing every time.

```
private void PackageExecute()
    {
        try
        {
            TraceService("Another entry at " + DateTime.Now);
            //Instansiate an DTS RunTime Application Object
            Application app = new Application();
            TraceService("loading system From File system");
            //Create package Container to hold the package.
            //And Load the Package Using the Application Object.
            Package package = app.LoadPackage(@"C:\Users\kavita.verma\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsServiceTest\WindowsServiceTest\Package1.dtsx", null);

            TraceService("Execution Started");
            DTSExecResult result = package.Execute();
            // print the result
            TraceService(result.ToString());
            TraceService("Execution Completed");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TraceService("Execution Error" + ex);
        }

    }
```

Comment: could you please provide the error details

Comment: Does the account your service is running under have access to that path?

Comment: so the logon account for the service is using kavita.verma or some kind of system admin user?

Comment: i am not sure if this is what you r asking. When running from cmd promt i have to configure this> i have to go to Services and this change its property to Log On as: Local System account and check the Allow service to interact with desktop.

Comment: Local System probably does not have access to your private folder. Change the Logon As to your account and see if it fixes the error. Then have a think about using a proper service account.

Comment: You need to give more information. "It's not working" is the most frustrating thing to read - it tells me nothing.

Comment: its not working . if service account property change than error will come as during installing a service is "The Installation failed,and the rollback has been performed"..

Comment: Isn't your service already installed? After it is installed go into services.msc and change the logon account.

Comment: Or you could just move your package to a public folder that everyone has access to.

Comment: After it is installed go into services.msc and change the logon account.than error come as access is denied

Comment: It appears you don't have sufficient access on your own computer to do what you need. Why dpn't you move your package to a public place instead. Or do some reading on service accounts

Comment: I just put my package in othe drive and run the service than package result come as --Failure  and out put come as start service
Another entry at 4/8/2013 5:55:25 PM
loading system From File system
Execution Started
Failure
Execution Completed for whole execution of service

Comment: I can't tell from your description whether the service can't start or whether it did start but the package failed. Is it the same error message as before?

Comment: simply services run well.. bt package failed

Comment: So now your package is still running under local service account, so there is probably another security issue. local service can't get to some resource that the package requires, like a file or a database connection.

Comment: How to solve it problem